# Custom Controll like Dock menu of Mac os in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, custom-controls

[image]

I want to create a custom controll like Dock of Mac os.
in which i want  to display all items horizantally with shadow, and on select to the perticular item display focusing Dot like DOck in mac os and display perticular view corresponding to perticular selected item with genie effect or popup like view.

simple view is displayed in image above.

any help will be appericiated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://github.com/Nichchenakolla/Dock-IOS/tree/master/Dock-IOS)  from Nichchenakolla meets all your requirement, there is just no focusing dot but you can easily add that as you are free to provide any image there.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.
can you suggest some more examples like this ?
i want to display popup like view on selected item as shown in figure, and also want to make all items horizantally scroll if possible.

Comment: We would never get exact sample code as our requirement tejas, now as we got Dock code, you should turn your search towards "UICollectionView" which will be popped up after selecting item inside dock...The origin of that pop up can be easily handled then ...